# Horizontal Scrolling Flash Game/Large Horizontal Scene

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, cs4

I'm currently learning Flash (CS4, AS3) and am creating a game. I have currently 1 flv file with 4 scenes, I then move from left to right and then to scene 2 and go from left to right. This is the game where items pop up that need to be clicked on and you get points.

Is there any way I can combine these onto 1 scene? Flash only allows you to have a maximum of 2880px wide. The reason for this is the transition between the scenes is RUBBISH and that my AS is not working correctly in between scenes (it loses values).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Nathan

Answer (score 2):

The common way of doing [scrolling is by using tiles](http://www.8bitrocket.com/newsdisplay.aspx?newspage=17171). Basically you use small building blocks to draw the background in the game. Using this technique you can have an almost limitless width in your game. Check out the article linked to above!

Comment: At the moment that doesn't seem like the best solution as the way my game is laid out doesn't suite this method.

Thank you very much for both of your answers!

Comment: Nathan: if you need to, you can make the tiles very large. And they don't really have to be bitmaps either - they can be any type of DisplayObject.

Answer (score 0):

And although it is still technically tile-based scrolling, if your background really isn't composed of individual small tiles, you can still split it up into 2880px wide bitmapDatas, push those bitmapDatas onto an array, and at run-time copyPixels the required pixels from there onto your screen.